# How much Vector Grid is intersected by another polygon layer using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector-grid, intersect

I have a grid 5X5 sqkm and another vector layer with 2 different land cover type (let's say "forest"/"no forest").

I wish all the squares composing the grid to get a value ranging from 0 to 1 accordingly to the extent of their area intersecting the "forest".

A square completely covered by forest should assume the value 1, while a square with no forest at all a 0 value.

How can I determine how much of a Vector Grid is intersected by another polygon layer using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Comment: What precisely have you tried, and where are you stuck?  Please ask about just one GIS product in a question like this because while similar the steps will not be identical in the two GIS products that you mention.